# Get the element at index "elemIndex" in a list

Tags: haskell

Basically I'm trying to get the n'th element in a list using the value from the `elementIndex` function.
Here is my code:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe

names = ["Molly", "Jack", "Perrie", "Adele", "Jake", "Lily", "Lawrence", "Ethan"] :: [String]
ages = [5,1,8,9,6,4,7,3] :: [Int]

getAge :: String -> [String] -> [Int] -> Maybe Int
getAge name names ages = getIntAtIndex index ages
    where
        index = elemIndex name names

getIntAtIndex :: Maybe Int -> [Int] -> Maybe Int
getIntAtIndex n [] = Nothing
getIntAtIndex n (x:xs)
        | (isNothing n) or (n < 0) = Nothing
        | n == 0 = Just x
        | otherwise = getIntAtIndex (n-1) xs
```

`getAge` searches a `name` in `names` and returns the age from the same `index` in `ages`.
but when I try to load the file in `ghci` I get:

```
Prelude> :l test.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, interpreted )

test.hs:15:11:
    Couldn't match expected type `(t0 Bool -> Bool) -> Bool -> Bool'
                with actual type `Bool'
    The function `isNothing' is applied to three arguments,
    but its type `Maybe Int -> Bool' has only one
    In the expression: (isNothing n) or (n < 0)
    In a stmt of a pattern guard for
                   an equation for `getIntAtIndex':
      (isNothing n) or (n < 0)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I've already tried the `!! operator` but it only accepts Int, so I added the function `getIntAtIndex` in order to acheive this.
Could someone point me where is the error? Because I can't see it.

I would expect `getAge "Jack" names` to return `1` and `getAge "Bill" names` to return `Nothing`

Thanks

Comment: Haskell isn't Python. The short-circuit operator for Boolean OR is `||`, not `or` (which is a function).

Comment: Even if we write `(isNothing n) or (n < 0)` as  `(isNothing n) || (n < 0)` this is still wrong: the first part requires `n` to be a `Maybe something` while the second one requires `n` to be a number e.g. `Int`. These two types are not compatible. I'd avoid using `isNothing` and use pattern matching e.g. `getIntAtIndex Nothing [] = ...`. I must add that I can't figure out why one would want to pass `Maybe Int` for the index: I'd use a plain `Int`.

Comment: thanks, for your input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `or` as an infix operator, you need to surround it in backticks. GHC thinks `isNothing n` is being applied to the function `or`.

Also, you probably want `(||) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool` not `or :: [Bool] -> Bool`